# Why APIPA doesn't work with multiple network adapters?

Tags: networking, ip, dhcp

I connected 3 cameras to 3 network adapters in my PC. I don't have DHCP, so I thought APIPA will do the work. But, camera's installation guide says "If a PC is equipped with multiple network adapters, APIPA can only be used on one of the adapters. If APIPA is enabled on more than one adapter, the network will not operate properly."

I've read about APIPA and that it has private IP range and 255.255.0.0 subnet mask, but I still don't understand why it doesn't work if each camera gets unique IP address from APIPA?

Answer (score 3):

Your OS will choose only one interface to talk to that subnet on.

Why are you using separate network cards? Just use a switch.

Comment: I cannot use switch because I need each camera to send with max traffic simultaneously to each adapter and the switch will limit the traffic

Comment: @theateist Three cameras can't possibly saturate a gigabit link even at their highest possible settings. Try using a [bandwidth calculator](http://www.supercircuits.com/resources/tools/network-ip-security-camera-system-bandwidth-calculator) for yourself. And even if the cameras have 100Mbit links you can connect them to a gigabit switch...

Comment: @Michael my cams transmit ~61MB (2560x1500 frame at 16 fps) per second. So, for 3 cams it's 183MB that is greater than 125MB(=gigabit). That's why I cannot use switch

Comment: @theateist I think you have mixed up megabits and megabytes.

Comment: @Michael, I don't I've mixed up MB and Mb. Each camera transmit 61MB per second. 3 cameras transmit 183MB per second. The bandwidth of single GigE is 1Gb per second == 125MB per second

Comment: @theateist Exactly which camera is this?

Answer (score 0):

Get a switch and connect the cameras and pc to it.

Failing that, bridge all 3 network adapters together to emulate a switch then you only have one virtual adapter to worry about.

The reason it doesn't work is because with all adapters having the same subnet the OS thinks they are all connected to the same network and will only try sending out one of the 3 adapters.

Comment: So, if I understand you corectly OS will randomly choose one of the adapter and send, right?

Comment: It wont be entirely random, but yes, it will just pick one.  The routing table of the computer will say that the subnet is reachable through each of these 3 adapters, in this order.  It will pick the first one in the list and try to talk to all 3 devices through that interface.